# How to instantiate class with StructureMap by the class generic specifier?

Tags: c#, structuremap

If I have abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> 
   where T: ISomeInterface 
{ ... }
```

and two derived classes like

```
public class A : BaseClass<Model1>
{ ... }

public class B : BaseClass<Model2>
{ ... }
```

Is there a way to setup StrunctureMap to instantiate corresponded class by given model inherited from ISomeInterface with StructureMap?

```
public class static MyFactory
{
    public static BaseClass<T> Get<T>()
             where T: ISomeInterface 
    {
       // StructureMap instantiates class here
       ...?
    }
}

MyFactory.Get<Model1>(); // returns instance of A
MyFactory.Get<Model2>(); // returns instance of B
```

I want StructureMap configuration works well for any new such classes (like `class C : BaseClass<Model3>`) to be automatically recognized by StructureMap, without configuring additional interface->class mapping

Comment: where T: ISomeInterface, new() <- this goes on your class def
{ 
   return new T(); <- this goes in your Get method.
}
?  (Have I misunderstood the question?)

Comment: 1) Get method instantiates class inherited from BaseClass<T>, not T 
2) I need instantiation to be done with help of StructureMap as this classes might have other interface references that need to be resolved automatically with StructureMap as well

Comment: I think I understand now...will have to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called batch-registration and this is how to do that in StructureMap:

```
var container = new Container(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(BaseClass<>));
        scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
        scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(BaseClass<>));
    });
});
```

Comment: Then how can I instantiate this classes? If I run `container.GetInstance<BaseClass<Model1>>()` I got StructureMap exception "202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily BaseClass`1[[...Model1...]], .."

Comment: though if I configure it with `x.For<BaseClass<Model1>>().Use<A>()` I have no problem in instantiating it with the same command `container.GetInstance<BaseClass<Model1>>()`. I just do not want to keep in mind adding separate mapping (`For<>.Use<>`) for every new such class

Comment: Now it works! Thanks
This line actually helped: `scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(BaseClass<>));`

Comment: this code worked fine before, but stopped working in StructureMap 3.1